# Generate SSH Keypairs (private/public) without ssh-keygen

Tags: ruby, ssh, ssh-keys, net-ssh

I'm working on a Ruby/Rack application that needs to generate SSH keypairs.  As much as I'd like to call `ssh-keygen` from the application, I can't because it's designed to run on Heroku and they don't support calling that command.

I've been able to get private/public RSA keys using OpenSSL in the Ruby standard library doing the following:

```
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate(2048)
# => -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- ....
key.public_key
# => -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- ....
```

Unfortunately an RSA public key and an SSH public key is not the same thing, even though they can be generated from the same RSA key.  An SSH public key looks something like the following:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwA.....
```

Is it possible to generate SSH keys or convert RSA keys to SSH in Ruby without using `ssh-keygen`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out this was much more complicated than I anticipated.  I ended up writing the [SSHKey gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/sshkey) to pull it off (source code [on GitHub](https://github.com/bensie/sshkey)).  SSH Public keys are encoded totally differently from the RSA public key provided. Data type encoding for SSH keys are defined in section #5 of [RFC #4251](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4251.txt).

Answer (score 29):

It may not have been the case when you had the problem, but the [net-ssh](https://rubygems.org/gems/net-ssh) library patches [OpenSSL::PKey::RSA](https://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/OpenSSL/PKey/RSA.html) and [::DSA](https://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/OpenSSL/PKey/DSA.html) with two methods:

`#ssh_type` - returns `"ssh-rsa"` or `"ssh-dss"` as appropriate

and `#to_blob` - returns the public key in OpenSSH binary-blob format.  If you base64-encode it, it's the format you're looking for.

```
require 'net/ssh'

key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 2048

type = key.ssh_type
data = [ key.to_blob ].pack('m0')

openssh_format = "#{type} #{data}"
```

Comment: This is a really nice and succinct solution.

Comment: note, net/ssh is quite a big gem and that like monkey patching and so on. @bensie's answer is a much more lightweight approach

Answer (score -1):

```
key.public_key.to_pem
```

The full process including key encryption is documented here: http://stuff-things.net/2009/12/11/generating-rsa-key-pairs-in-ruby/

Comment: OpenSSL::PKey::RSA#to_pem seems to just provide string output, it does not convert it to the SSH public key format.

Comment: I also tried simply prepending the "ssh-rsa" and appending the comment syntax to the string, but it's not the same and is not recognized as a valid public key.