# Invalid OpenSSH key format when importing an ec2 key form an existing one

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am using the ruby EC2 SDK, Version 2. The private key material of a key generated with EC2 is stored in a string. I am trying to generate the public key material that is necessary to import the key into EC2 using `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA`

After that I am trying to [import](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Resource.html#import_key_pair-instance_method) the key pair.

It looks like this:

```
kk=OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new my_private_key_material
pub=kk.public_key
ec2.import_key_pair({key_name: "my_key", public_key_material: pub.export})
```

The API is throwing this error:

```
*** Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidKeyFormat Exception: Key is not in valid OpenSSH public key format
```

I am not sure what is wrong and how to generate the public key material correctly. I already tried to Base64 encode the public key string without success.

**Edit**

I tried a couple of new things.
I generated a new key using the EC2 web console from scratch and then geneerated the public one the way Raphael points out below with

```
openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out mykey.pub
```

The key is not encrypted.

Whey trying to import the public key, either with the web console or by code, I get the same error.

**Edit 2**

I found this.

When generating the public key with a different command, it works:

```
ssh-keygen -y
```

The generated public key looks different. It starts with

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADA....
```

While the first generated one starts with

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG....
```

Now the question is how to generate the first format in ruby. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749858/rsa-public-key-format) post on different formats.

Comment: Is your key encrypted?

Comment: No. Not according to [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129724/how-to-check-if-an-ssh-private-key-has-passphrase-or-not). It also has no passphrase and was generated using the standard EC2 procedure.

Comment: Are you able to generate the pub key from the private using other tool, like: `openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -pubout > mykey.pub`.
Try to do this to check the validity of private key generated. Maybe some parameters are missing or wrong.

Comment: OK. I just tried it and generated the key like this. It was generated, but when importing it, I got the same message. This time I imported it directly using the EC2 management console. I repeated the whole procedure with a freshly generated key. Same issue.

Comment: Sorry, was the key pem encoded? I forgot the paramenter in the comand, it should be `openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out mykey.pub`

Comment: How did you generate the key? Did u use 'create_key_pair' API or ssh keygen or openssl ?

Comment: @Raphael, thx again. I tried it but without success.

Comment: @agent420, create_key_pair or directly using the ec2 web console UI

Comment: When you use EC2 console or AWS SDKs to generate a key, it's public key is already stored by AWS EC2. You do not need to import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solved it by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270386/generate-ssh-keypairs-private-public-without-ssh-keygen).

It turned out the public key had to be generated in a different way

```
kk=OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new my_private_key_material
key=kk.public_key

type = key.ssh_type
data = [ key.to_blob ].pack('m0')

openssh_format = "#{type} #{data}"

ec2.import_key_pair({key_name: "my_key", public_key_material: openssh_format})
```

Comment: It's interesting and odd, the pack(m0) encodes the string to Base64, how did you try to encode it before? was it using Base64.encode64?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation suggests that key contents must be encoded in Base64 client-side, however this is not the case: The SSH key contents should be provided as-is, in the format "ssh-rsa XXXXX....".

Answer (score 0):

Rory is right. In NodeJS below code worked.

```
let keypair = fs.readFileSync(homedir + '/.ssh/id_rsa.pub');
result = await ec2.importKeyPair({
    KeyName: 'KeyPairName',
    PublicKeyMaterial: keypair,
}).promise();
```

Answer (score 0):

I m using Ruby SDK V3 and this is work for me to import key to AWS

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk-ec2'


key_content = File.read('/home/xxx/keys/sshkey.pub')
ec2_client =  Aws::EC2::Client.new()
resp = ec2_client.import_key_pair({
  dry_run: false,
  key_name: "test-ruby-key",
  public_key_material: key_content,
})
```

Hope it helpful!